# Center-of-gravity list search?

Tags: python, list, search

Let say I have a hidden list of numbers, for example:

```
[3397, 3343, 3297, 3251, 3215,
 3159, 3107, 3061, 3029, 2979,
 2939, 2879, 2829, 2781, 2733,
 2673, 2615, 2579, 2633, 2669,
 2713]
```

I cannot see the list; I can only probe for individual values. How do I find the smallest value with the least number of probes?

What I know of the list is that it has center of gravity, i.e. they are sorted towards this position from both sides. In the above case, the list is sorted outward from position 17 (value 2579) in both directions.

---

Based on Prune recommendation :

```
 def mini(lst, low, high):
    zrange = (high-low)
    if zrange <= 3 : return min(lst[low:high])
    i25 = int(low + zrange*0.25); i50 = int(low + zrange*0.5); i75 = int(low + zrange*0.75)
    q25 = lst[i25]; q50 = lst[i50]; q75 = lst[i75]

    if   q25 <= q50 <= q75 : high = i50
    elif q25 >= q50 >= q75 : low = i50
    elif q25 > q50 < q75 :
        low = i25; high = i75

    return mini(lst, low, high)

def minis(lst):
    low = 0; high = len(lst)
    return mini(lst, low, high)
```

Any other takers on different algorithm.
To lower the probes, I have to make it iteration, rather than recursion.
This way I can reuse probes.

Comment: Seems like you want to do some type of binary search. I'd try that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a binary divide-and-conquer algorithm.  Probe the three quartile locations of the list.  Call them `a, b, c`; let the endpoints be `L` and `R`.  Given that the list is partially sorted, you have these possibilities and actions:

```
a < b < c
    The low point must be to the left of `b`.
    Recur on the list from `L` to `b`.
    You already have `a` as the midpoint of this slice.

a > b > c
    The low point must be to the right of `b`.
    Recur on the list from `b` to `L`.
    You already have `c` as the midpoint of this slice.

a > b < c
    The low point must be between `a` and `c`.
    Recur on that portion of the list.
    You already have `b` as the midpoint of this slice.
```

I trust that you can handle the base cases, when you have no unprobed elements remaining.

Since you cut the list in half each time, you will have log2(n) iterations, with 2 additional probes on each iteration.  There is an extra probe on the first, and perhaps only one on the last.